# prove $\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}(y+ix) \equiv y^p - x^{p-1}y \mod p$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation

The coefficient of $y^p$ is obviously 1 and coefficient of $x^{p-1}y$ is $(p-1)!$ which by wilson's theorem is $-1 \pmod{p}$

Now further thinking leads me to all the coefficients as being stirling numbers of first kind. And all the stirling numbers ${p \brack k}$ for $1 < k < p$ are divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime.

**But how to prove this?** If each stirling number of first kind can be written as a binomial coefficient or product of binomial coefficients of $p$, then we are all set.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the polynomials (over the field $\Bbb F_p$)
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}(x-i)&
g(x)&=x^p-x
\end{align}
They have the same roots, leading coefficient and same degree, hence $f(x)=g(x)$.